# Is every geometry contained in a maximal geometry?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Following the classical definition (made prominent by Thurston, I believe, but correct me if I am mistaken) we define a *geometry* to be a pair $(M,G)$, where

1) $M$ is a smooth and $1$-connected (i.e, connected and simply-connected) manifold,

2) $G \subset Diff(M)$ (endowed with the compact-open topology), such that the induced action of $G$ on $M$ is transitive and for some (then any) $x \in M$, the stabilizer $G_x \subset G$ is a *compact* subgroup.

3) There is a subgroup $H \subseteq G$, acting *cocompactly*, *freely* and *properly discontiuously* on $M$. This is equivalent to saying that the action of $H$ on $M$ is that of a covering group and the quotient $H / M$ is compact.

We say that two geometries $(M,G)$ and $(M',G')$ are *equivalent* is there is a diffeomorphism $\phi: M \to M'$, such that the obvious induced homeomorphism $\phi_*: Diff(M) \to Diff(M')$, maps $G$ homeomorphically onto $G'$.

Under this relation, the collection of equivalence classes of geometries form a set, equipped with a natural order $\subseteq$, so that $[(M,G)] \subseteq [(M',G')]$ if there are respective representatives $(M,G)$ and $(M',G')$ and a diffeomorphism $\psi: M \to M'$, such that $\psi_*(G) \subseteq G'$. With this in mind, define a *model geometry* (or *maximal* geometry) to be a class of geometries that is not properly contained in any other class of geometries with respect to the above define order.

My question is now the following, as stated in the title: *Is every geometry contained in a maximal geometry ?*

At least to me, this situation doesn't seem suitable for applying Zorn's Lemma: There is neither an obvious upper bound for a chain of geometries, nor is it clear whether the order is even antisymmetric (although it clearly does satisfy both reflexivity and transitivity). However, without the help of Zorn's Lemma, i cannot see a way to give an affirmative answer to this question. Moreover, all geometries I know are contained in a maximal geometry.
Does anyone have a (positive, negative) answer to this question ? If it is negative, I am very interested in an explicit example of a such a geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is always a maximal geometry. Here are two key facts which one can use to prove the claim:

1. $G_x$ acts faithfully on $T_xM$, hence, there is a natural embedding $G_x\to GL(n, {\mathbb R})$, $n=dim(M)$. (Hint: Put a $G_x$-invariant Riemannian metric on $M$.)
2. $GL(n, {\mathbb R})$ contains a (unique up to conjugation) compact subgroup $O(n)$ containing (up to conjugation) any other compact subgroup.

Comment: I know that $G_x$ must be contained in (a conjugate of) $O(n)$. It is also clear to me that my question is essentially equivalent to the question of whether or not a nested set  $(K_j)_{j \in J}$ of closed subgroups of (a conjugate of) $O(n)$ eventually stabilizes (or, more generally, have a colimit that is closed as a subset of $O(n)$). I know it to be true under the additional assumption that each member of the set is connected. So far, I don't know how to prove it in the non-connected case....

Comment: No, in general it does not stabilize and, in general, the union of compact subgroups is not a compact subgroup of $O(n)$ (think about roots of unity in $U(1)$). However, they all are contained in a compact subgroup, which is enough to define an invariant Riemannian metric on $M$: Invariant under all subgroups in your chain. Then you take your Lie group to be the full isometry group of this metric.

Comment: A more challenging problem is to consider geometric structures in the sense of Ehresmann, where $G_x$ is no longer required to be compact (but $G$ is still a Lie group acting smoothly). The existence of maximal structures in this setting would be harder to prove, I am not even sure it is true.

Comment: Ah, so let me try to see if I understood your hints correctly. Let  $(M,G)$ be a geometry and $\{(M,G_i)\}_{i \in I}$ the set of all other geometries containing $(M,G)$. Let $x \in M$ be fixed and $K_i$ be the (respective) point stabilizers of $x$. Then the $K_i$ all lie in a fixed compact subgroup $L$ of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ (a conjugate of $O(n)$). Use the finite haar measure of $L$ to define a metric $g$ on $M$ invariant under the action of all $G_i$. Let $H := Isom(M,g)$ and consider the geometry $(M,H)$.

Comment: Since any geometry containing $(M,G)$ must also be contained in $(M,H)$, this proves that $(M,H)$ is indeed maximal. Is this the right idea ?

Comment: @BerniWaterman: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66293/discussion-between-berni-waterman-and-moishe-cohen).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete answer, based on the hints given by Moishe Cohen and expanded from the comments below his answer:
Let $(M,G)$ be a geometry. Use Zorn to find a *maximal* nested set $\{(M,G_i)\}_{i \in I}$ of geometries containing $(M,G)$. This means that:

a) Each $(M,G_i)$ contains $(M,G)$.

b) For every pair $i,j \in I$, there is some $k \in I$ such that $(M,G_k)$ contains both $(M,G_i)$ and $(M,G_j)$.

c) $\{(M,G_i)\}_{i \in I}$ is not properly contained in other set of geometries with properties $a)$ and $b)$.

For fixed $x \in M$, denote by $K \subset G$ and $K_i \subset G_i$ for $i \in I$ the respective compact stabilizers of $x$. By considering the induced action on $T_xM$, this means that each $K_i$ naturally embeds as a compact subgroup into $GL(n,\mathbb R)$. Since each of them contains $K$ and $K$ is contained in a unique maximal compact subgroup $L$ (in fact, $L$ is a conjugate of $O(n)$), it follows that each $K_i$ is also contained in $L$. Therefore, we can define an inner product $\langle \; , \; \rangle_x$ on $T_xM$ invariant under the action of $L$, and thus invariant under the action of each $K_i$.

Now let $y \in M$ be arbitrary. Define an inner product $\langle \; , \; \rangle_y$ on $T_yM$ as the push-forward of $\langle \; , \; \rangle_x$ via some $\alpha \in G_i$ sending $x$ to $y$. To see that this definition doesn't depend on the choice of $\alpha$, note that for some other $\beta \in G_j$ sending $x$ to $y$, we have that $\beta^{-1} \alpha \in K_l \subset G_l$, where $(M,G_l)$ is a geometry containing both $(M,G_i)$ and $(M,G_j)$ (whose existence is guaranteed by b) ).

The collection of those inner products define a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$. Set $H := Isom(M,g)$. Then $(M,H)$ is a geometry containing all $(M,G_i)$, as $g$ is $G_i$-invariant for each $i \in I$, by definition. Finally, to see that $(M,H)$ is maximal, assume by contradiction that $(M,H)$ is properly contained in some geometry $(M,H')$. Then, the set $\{(M,G_i)\}_{i \in I} \cup \{(M,H')\}$ would be a nested set properly containing $\{(M,G_i)\}_{i \in I}$, a contradiction to property $c)$.

Note that this does *not* show that the maximal geometry containing a given $(M,G)$ is unique. Indeed, this seems to be true only in some cases, such as when $dim(M) \leq 2$ and $dim(M) = 3$ with $\partial M = \emptyset$. I don't know how the situation is in the general case.